# Как сделать, что-бы созданная кнопка не исчезала?

Tags: javascript

Сделал кнопку, кнопка работает и появляется при переходе на другую страницу. Как сделать так, чтобы она ещё появлялась при загрузке страницы?

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var oldHref = document.location.href;
    var bodyList = document.querySelector("body")
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        if (oldHref != document.location.href) {
            oldHref = document.location.href;

            var mydivimg = document.createElement("div");
            var button_start_stop = document.createElement('button');
            button_start_stop.id = 'button_start_stop';
            button_start_stop.type = 'button';
            button_start_stop.innerHTML = 'Старт';
            button_start_stop.style.cssText = "position: absolute; z-index: 9; border-style: none; top: 459px;\
            left: 202px; width: 141px; height: 35px; outline: none;";

            let id;
            button_start_stop.onclick = () => {
                if (id === undefined) {
                    id = setInterval(() => {
                        hothearts.manager.kiss.process();
                        button_start_stop.innerHTML = 'Стоп';
                    }, 500);
                } else {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    id = undefined;
                    button_start_stop.innerHTML = 'Старт';
                }
            };
            const container = document.querySelector(".hothearts-page_burn_out_holder");
            container.appendChild(button_start_stop);
        }
    });

    var config = {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    };

    observer.observe(bodyList, config);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать так, чтобы она ещё появлялась при загрузке страницы?

Собрать действия по добавлению кнопки в функцию... Потом вызвать ее при собственно загрузке страницы.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var oldHref = document.location.href;
  var bodyList = document.querySelector("body")
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (oldHref != document.location.href) {
      createBtn()
    }
  });
  //
  function createBtn() {
    oldHref = document.location.href;

    var mydivimg = document.createElement("div");
    var button_start_stop = document.createElement('button');
    button_start_stop.id = 'button_start_stop';
    button_start_stop.type = 'button';
    button_start_stop.innerHTML = 'Старт';
    // отключил для наглядности
    /*
    button_start_stop.style.cssText = "position: absolute; z-index: 9; border-style: none; top: 459px;\
          left: 202px; width: 141px; height: 35px; outline: none;";
    */
    let id;
    button_start_stop.onclick = () => {
      if (id === undefined) {
        id = setInterval(() => {
          hothearts.manager.kiss.process();
          button_start_stop.innerHTML = 'Стоп';
        }, 500);
      } else {
        clearInterval(id);
        id = undefined;
        button_start_stop.innerHTML = 'Старт';
      }
    };
    const container = document.querySelector(".hothearts-page_burn_out_holder");
    container.appendChild(button_start_stop);
  }
  var config = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  observer.observe(bodyList, config);
  createBtn()
};
```

```html
<div class='hothearts-page_burn_out_holder'></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает. Но я столкнулся ещё с одной проблемой. Если нажать на кнопку, запускается setInterval. Если обновить страницу, то он отключается. А вот если перейти на другую страницу и вернутся, то процесс всё равно работает. Как бы сделать так, чтобы при переходе на другую страницу выполнить clearInterval(id);

Comment: @User, как вариант - при старте `setInterval()` на `window` можно навесить событие `onunload` и в нем делать `clearInterval()`

Comment: `window.onunload=function(){clearInterval(id);};` сделал так. Да, процесс отключается. И снова проблема. Если нажать на кнопу старт, затем нажать стоп, перейти на другую страницу, снова вернутся, то при нажании кнопка работает. А вот если нажать старт и не отключая перейти на другую страницу, затем вернутся, то кнопка есть, но при нажатии на неё ничего не присходит, кнопка не запускает процесс. Меняется надписть, а процесс не идёт. И работь она начинает только после обновления страницы.

Comment: кроме того сейчас заметил, что процес при переходе на другую страницу не всегда отключается.

Comment: @User, тебе остается только тестить свой код и смотреть с какими ситуациями ты сталкиваешься...

Comment: ksa, а можно что-бы моя кнопка создавалась ещё при появлении элемента `contest-popup-main-avatar` ? Как отследить появление этого элемента и что-бы кнопочка появилась?

Comment: @User, отслеживать появление элемента на странице можно используя `MutationObserver` - https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer

Comment: ksa, я помню тот пример для отслеживания с MutationObserver, который ты давал. Но у меня всё же ну никак не хватает мозгов, что-бы в данный код что-то добаввиь, что-бы при появлении определённого элемента создавалась `createBtn()`. Не сочти за труд помоги решить неразрешиую для меня задачу. Все попытки мои не увенчались успехом.

Comment: @User, будет более уместным тебе создать другой вопрос в котором можно будет показать решение...

Comment: ksa, так и сделаю

Comment: ksa, тут мой вопрос [ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1543037/ ]