# Как отследить появление элемента с помощью MutationObserver и создать свой элемент?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть рабочий код кнопки, который эмитирует нажатие и удерживание клавиатурной кнопки пробела. Кнопка создается при загрузке страницы и если меняется ссылка в строке браузера. Как сделать так, что-бы кнопка создавалась ещё и при обнаружении элемента   `contest-popup-main-avatar` а при переходе по ссылке создавалась один раз.

```
window.onload = function() {
       button_start_stop_contest = document.createElement('input');
       var oldHrefContest = document.location.href;
       var bodyList1 = document.querySelector("body");
       let id4;
       var observerContest = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
       if (oldHrefContest != document.location.href)
       {
          createBtnContest();
       }
      });
      
      function createBtnContest() {
        oldHrefContest = document.location.href;
        button_start_stop_contest.id = 'button_start_stop_contest';
        button_start_stop_contest.type = 'button';
        button_start_stop_contest.value = 'Старт';
        button_start_stop_contest.style.cssText = "position: absolute; z-index: 99999;\
        border-style: none; top: 0px; left: 7px; width: 75px; height: 70px; background: #f08d3b;\
        border-radius: 4px; color: #fff; border-bottom: 2px solid #b46728; line-height: 18px;\
        transition background-color 0.3s; text-align: left;text-align: center;\
        text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #c57836; box-sizing: border-box; outline: 0 none; border: none;\
        font-size: 16px; letter-spacing: 2px; padding: 13px;";
    
         
       button_start_stop_contest.onclick = () => {
        if (id4 === undefined) {
          id4 = setInterval(() => {
         
           var evt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode':32, 'which':32}); 
          document.dispatchEvent(evt); }, 0);
       
        button_start_stop_contest.value = 'Стоп';
            
        } else {
         
          button_start_stop_contest.value = 'Старт';
            clearInterval(id4);
         
          id4 = undefined;
       
       }};
    
       const containerContest = document.querySelector(".contest-popup-buttons-container")
       containerContest.appendChild(button_start_stop_contest);
    
      }
      var config = {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
      };
      observerContest.observe(bodyList1, config);
      createBtnContest();
     };
```